# Iterate over numpy array to fill a python list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm iterating over a numpy array to apply a function through each element and add the new value to a list so I can keep the original data.

The problem is: it's kinda slow.

Is there a better way to do this (without changing the original array)?

```
import numpy as np
original_data = np.arange(0,16000, dtype = np.float32)
new_data = [i/max(original_data) for i in original_data]
print('done')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
new_data = original_data/original_data.max()
```

Numpy already performs this operation element-wise.

In your code there is an **extra source of slowness**: each call `max(original_data)` will result in an iteration over all elements from `original_data`, making your cost proportional to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This approach will help alot.